# Ruby. Random numbers generator

Tags: ruby, random

I'm new to Ruby. I just want to know if there is a way to create random numbers in the following fashion:

1) Generate 45 random numbers.

2) Random number generated can be repeated only up to 5 times

I tried using the following approach.

```
45.times do |x|
  puts x.rand(1..9)
end
```

How can I achieve max occurrence of a number be 5?

Comment: Do you require 45 random numbers in the range 0 to 5 ?

Comment: nope. I wanted to create 45 random numbers. But if a number reached more than 5, stop using that number in the random numbers.

Comment: @EjayTan your explanation seems a bit complicated. You want a shuffled array containing each number from 1 to 9 exactly 5 times.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
Array.new(5) { (1..9).to_a }.flatten.shuffle
```

This generates an array in which all number form 1 to 9 exist exactly 5 times and shuffles that array randomly.

Depending on your needs you might use this array as it is or `pop` the next random number from it:

```
numbers = Array.new(5) { (1..9).to_a }.flatten.shuffle

3.times do 
  puts numbers.pop
end
```

Using `pop` returns a number and removes it from the array. That means after 45 circles the `numbers` array will be empty.

Comment: To could also use `Array#*` to avoid `flatten`. i.e.: `((1..9).to_a * 5).shuffle`

Comment: `3.times` should probably be `45.times`. Wouldn't it be cleaner to just remove elements until the array is empty instead of having the magic number `45` in there? Something like `while (n = numbers.pop); puts n; end`. Also note that `pop` removes the _last_ element which might be counterintuitive.

Comment: @Stefan I totally agree. I meant the `3.times` part only as an example how to use `pop` that is easily pasteable into the console. I guess the OP doesn't just want to write a program that prints the values to the console. Therefore IMO it depends on the usage of this randomly order array, how he might want to consume its content. But using `while` is certainly better than a magic number. You are right.